# Calling fprintf from dynamic library (c++)

Tags: c++

I'm creating a windows DLL library that contains a logging class, the log function in that class simply calls fprintf like this for testing purposes:

fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG:   %s\n", "Hello");

Now this call works fine if i use it from any function in any file in my other project (that uses the library) but if i put it anywhere in my library with the logging class it simply wont print anything.
I can see it runs the function correctly (using a simple exit(0); to test).

Now i'm still kinda new to the whole Library concept in c/c++ so there might be something i just don't understand, but otherwise i don't know why it doesn't work.

I tried searching here and on google, but i couldn't find anyone else with the same exact problem.
I use VC++ 2010

EDIT: I got the idea of passing the filepointer instead of just using stderr from the library, this causes an exception to be thrown however (the _tmpfname pointer of the file is NULL at the time of the throw, which im not sure is correct)

Comment: Do your DLL and main application both link against the same C runtime version?

Comment: Where can i find that information?

Comment: Looking at the manifest for 'the project' under the dependency tag i get the version 9.0.21022.8 But the manifest for the library doesn't generate a dependency tag or show a C runtime version elsewhere :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid doing this for any production code (it's ok for testing though).  The standard I/O streams belong to the application, and [the DLLs are guests in the house](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/12/02/9931183.aspx).  If you want to provide debug output, allow the application to setup a callback function for logging, e.g.:

```
// In your DLL's header file:
typedef void (*LogFunc)(const char *, ...);
void DLLEXPORT SetLogFunction(LogFunc logFunc);

// In your DLL's source file:
LogFunc g_LogFunc;
void DLLEXPORT SetLogFunction(LogFunc logFunc)
{
    g_LogFunc = logFunc;
}

...
// Then, instead of calling fprintf(stderr, "blah"), do this:
g_LogFunc("blah");
```

If you're just doing this for testing, you can write directly to `stderr`, but keep in mind that the DLL and the application must be linked against the same version of the C runtime in order for that to work.  The C runtime is itself a DLL, and if your DLL and the application specify different versions of the C runtime, you'll end up loading two separate copies of the C runtime into memory, each with their own idea of what `stderr` means.  When they're different, bad stuff happens.

In Visual Studio, to set the C runtime library you're using, open up your project settings and go to **Configuration Properties → C/C++ → Code Generation → Runtime Library** and make sure that both the DLL and the application are set to the exact same value (typically "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)" or "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)", depending on whether you're building a Debug or Release build).

Comment: Yes, I would avoid using `stderr` in any way from a DLL in production code -- I would always use a callback in that case.  That way, all of the interaction with `stderr` happens from the main application, and there's no chance of multiple conflicting C runtimes causing problems with that.

Comment: Sorry for the random comment deleting, i realized what you meant after posting xD Thanks alot for the help :)